# How to get python slicing to work with my c++ array class using SWIG

Tags: python, c++, arrays, swig

I have an an array class, Array1D, defined in c++ which essentially wraps the STL vector class. I extended this class so that I can display individual elements of the array vector. Here is the relevant code in my SWIG interface file:

```
namespace std{
    %template(dblVector) vector<double>;
}

%extend Array1D{
    double __getitem__(int index) {
        return (*self)[index];
    }
}
```

This allows me to access individual elements of the array in python:

```
>>> a = Array1D(10) # creates a c++ vector of length 10 with zeros
>>> a[0]
>>> 0
```

I want to be able to call `a[1:3]` for example, however, I get a TypeError when I try this:

```
TypeError: in method 'Array1D___getitem__', argument 2 of type 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that python passes a Slice object when calling the slice variant of the **getitem** and your function definition is expecting an int. You will need to write a version of **getitem** that takes PyObject* as a parameter and then you'd have to implement the slicing of the vector there.

I am writing this without being setup to actually test it, so take it with a grain of salt. But I would do something like the following.

```
%extend Array1D
{
    Array1D* __getitem__(PyObject *param) 
    {
        if (PySlice_Check(param))
        {
            /* Py_ssize_t might be needed here instead of ints */
            int len = 0, start = 0, stop = 0, step = 0, slicelength = 0;

            len = this->size(); /* Or however you get the size of a vector */

            PySlice_GetIndicesEx((PySliceObject*)param, len, &start, &stop, &step, &slicelength);

            /* Here do stuff in order to return an Array1D that is the proper slice
               given the start/stop/step defined above */
        }

        /* Unexpected parameter, probably should throw an exception here */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the following, but I am not sure what to do:

``    double __getitem__(PyObject* slice) {
        Note sure what to do here? 
    }``

Comment: I added some code, it is what I would try. There is a problem though, if ints are treated as PyObjects, then this method would get called when doing a[3] for instance, but you would need a different return type for that and I am not sure how to solve that problem. But if ints aren't treated like PyObjects, then you should be able to define both __getitem__ funcitons, one returning Array1D* and the other returning double.

Comment: This is fantastic! It worked, but I had to change `int` to `Py_ssize_t`. Also, what does `(PySliceObject*)param` do? I am new to C and not familiar with this notation.

Comment: That is a type cast. So our param is a pointer to an object of type `PyObject`, but `PySlice_GetIndicesEx()` takes a pointer to a `PySliceObject` as the first parameter. So first I check to see if param is really a `PySliceObject` by calling `PySlice_Check()`. Since I now know it is a `PySliceObject`, I can tell c++ to treat it as though it is a pointer to a `PySliceObject` using the `(PySliceObject*)` notation.

Comment: To put it another way, lets say you have a couple of objects defined. A `Cat` object, and a `Tiger` object that inherits from `Cat`. You can instantiate a `Tiger` object like this `Cat jerry = Tiger();` Note that the type of jerry is a Cat, but behind the scenes it really is a Tiger. This works because a tiger is a cat. But if we needed to access the Tiger specific features (like counting stripes as not all cats have stripes). You would need to cast it to a Tiger first like this. `int stripes = ((Tiger)jerry).stripeCount();`. The * simply means 'pointer to'.