# How to pass a tuple of slice objects to C via the python-C api

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I have an 2d matrix class in c that I am using in python. I want to be able to call the matrix class by passing a tuple of slice objects, e.g., A[1:2,1:2]. So far what I have is the following. The relevant C code for the `__getitem__` method looks like

```
   int __getitem__(PyObject *slices){       // get tuple of slice objects
       PyObject* slice1;                    // declare first slice object
       PyObject* slice2;                    // declare second slice object       
       slice1 = PyTuple_GetItem(slices, 0); // get first slice from tuple
       slice2 = PyTuple_GetItem(slices, 1); // get second slice from tuple

        // get start and stop of first slice (currently the following three lines do not work)  
        Py_ssize_t start, stop, step, length; 
        PySlice_GetIndicesEx(slice1,length,&start,&stop,&step); 

     return PySlice_Check(slice2) ; 
    }
```

This code checks whether slice2 is indeed a slice object using the `PySlice_Check` method.  If I comment out `PySlice_GetIndicesEx(slice1,length,&start,&stop,&step)`, I get a `1` as expected. However, if I leave this line in, I get an error:

```
cannot convert 'PyObject* {aka _object*}' to 'PySliceObject*' for argument '1' to 'int PySlice_GetIndicesEx(...
```

which means I cannot pass slice1 or slice2 into `PySlice_GetIndicesEx` since it needs a `PySliceObject` object.

How do I unravel the slice objects properly so I can pass it into `PySlice_GetIndicesEx.` This function takes in `PySliceObject` and not a `PyObject`, which is what slice1 and slice2 is, even though `PySlice_Check(slice1)` and `PySlice_Check(slice2)` both return a 1.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution thanks to [A. Taggart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206796/how-to-get-python-slicing-to-work-with-my-c-array-class-using-swig/23207308?noredirect=1#comment35531413_23207308).:

```
int __getitem__(PyObject *slices){
    PyObject* slice1;
    PyObject* slice2;    
    slice1 = PyTuple_GetItem(slices, 0);
    slice2 = PyTuple_GetItem(slices, 1);

    Py_ssize_t len = 0, start1 = 0, stop1 = 0, step1 = 0, slicelength1 = 0;
    Py_ssize_t start2 = 0, stop2 = 0, step2 = 0, slicelength2 = 0;
    len = (*self).size() // or however you get the length of the slice
    PySlice_GetIndicesEx((PySliceObject*)slice1,len,&start1,&stop1,&step1,&slicelength1);
    PySlice_GetIndicesEx((PySliceObject*)slice2,len,&start2,&stop2,&step2,&slicelength2);

return 0;
```

The key here is to pass `(PySliceObject*)slice1` which passes the slice object as a `PySliceObject`.

Answer (score 0):

`__getitem__` takes a single argument, which in your case is a tuple of two slice-objects. That means that in C, `slices` points to a single tuple containing two slice-objects.

```
   PyObject* indices;
   PyObject* slice1;
   PyObject* slice2;
   indices = PyTuple_GetItem(slices, 0); // get tuple
   slice1 = PyTuple_GetItem(indices, 0); // get first slice from tuple
   slice2 = PyTuple_GetItem(indices, 1); // get second slice from tuple
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, when I try using `PySlice_GetIndicesEx(slice1,length,&start,&stop,&step)` I get the same error: `error: cannot convert 'PyObject* {aka _object*}' to 'PySliceObject*' for argument '1' to 'int PySlice_GetIndices`. Is there another way to get the start and stop values of the slice1 object?